# Different ways to invoke system calls

Tags: c, assembly, system-calls

In some code, I can see system call are invoked in a strange way, take `sched_yield` as an example:

```
#define __NR_sys_sched_yield    __NR_sched_yield

inline _syscall0(void, sys_sched_yield);
```

And then we can use `sys_sched_yield()`.
I'm curious what's the difference between using `sched_yield` directly and this way.
In src/include/asm/unistd, `_syscall0` is defined:

```
#define _syscall0(type,name)  \
type name(void)     \
{        \
    long __res;      \
    __asm__ volatile ("int $0x80"  \
    : "=a" (__res)    \
    : "0" (__NR_##name));   \
    __syscall_return(type,__res);  \
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably that's for systems where `sched_yield`might not be available.
As for differences, `sched_yield` returns `-1` on error and sets `ERRNO` while this implementation presumably returns the raw value from the kernel. Can't tell for sure since you haven't provided definition of `_syscall0` which must be a macro.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have edited my post to update something.

Answer (score 0):

This is linux which uses glibc.  BSD has a sched_yield but has its own libc.

This isn't strange.  The syscall0 macro issues an assembler `int 0x80` instruction and the syscall number is in the `rax` register [x86 architecture].  This is the standard syscall interface for linux.  Under the hood, all linux glibc functions that are syscall wrappers will do this [or use the more modern sysenter/sysexit x86 instruction pairings]

glibc has a tendency to "usurp" syscalls in its wrapper functions and add stuff around them.  For example, when you call `fork`, it [ultimately] calls `__libc_fork` which does a huge amount of extra stuff related to threads and file closure, etc.

Generally, glibc makes good choices.  But, sometimes highly experienced linux application programmers *want* the raw syscall behavior, particularly if they're writing system utilities or programs/libraries that must have close interaction with the kernel, device drivers, or device hardware.

Actually, `__libc_fork` doesn't invoke the `fork` *syscall*, it invokes the `clone` *syscall*, which is a [harder to use] superset of `fork`.  But, the plain old `fork` syscall still exists.  So, if you want that, you need the macro stuff--and I'll bet there's a `sys_fork` definition somewhere.

On the other hand, glibc might implement `sched_yield` ala POSIX as a nop returning -1 and setting errno to `ENOSYS`.  I just checked latest glibc source and I couldn't find the "real" implementation, except for mach.  It probably does do the real thing, I just couldn't find it.

Sometimes, linux has a syscall, but glibc doesn't want to support it, or they consider it to be too dangerous for an application programmer, so they leave out the wrapper function.  So, the macros are a way to "end around" glibc.

The probable reason for glibc implementing `sched_yield` as a nop, posix aside, is they consider it "bad" and probably tell you to use `nanosleep` instead.  I've used both and they are *not* the same, depending on your use case and desired effect.

Sometimes, you need to do the raw, inline syscall.  For example, the ELF loader [every system that supports ELF binaries must have one and linux's is `ld-linux.so`] is invoked by the kernel to load an ELF binary.  It must operate before glibc.so is available, because it is what actually links in glibc.so, the ELF loader must have some builtin syscalls for `open` and `read`

Also, most systems have a `syscall` library *function* that takes a variable number of arguments.  You could implement:

```
#define my_sched_yield() syscall(__NR_sched_yield)
#define my_read(_fd,_buf,_len) syscall(__NR_read,_fd,_buf,_len)
```

This function handles the kernel's syscall return value/error and sets errno.  That's what the `__syscall_return` macro had to do.

The `__NR_*` prefix is what linux uses, but other systems have `AUE_*` or `SYS_*`